# how can I add an extra character after a word search

Tags: bash, sed, awk, python, perl

I have the following field names

`demelog voyapro naisjdf naismc decoide decoccm travide travccm equiccm mariccm`

Below is a sample of my file. There are more columns before the first `fck=83`...

```
 fck=83;fcv=naismc;fcv=naisjdf;fck=83;fmd=1422811694,;fmd=1422811694;
 fck=83;fcv=demelog;fck=83;fmd=1423134370;
 fck=83;fcv=demelog;fck=83;fmd=1422292546;
 fck=83;fcv=demelog;fck=83;fmd=1421774352;
 fck=83;fcv=decoccm;fck=83;fmd=1422853444;
 fck=83;fcv=voyapro;fck=83;fmd=1422270462;
 fck=83;fcv=voyapro;fcv=demelog;fck=83;fmd=1422183999,;fmd=1422206234,;
```

Starting from fck=83 as you can see, I can have for `line 2` fcv=demelog and the relevant fmd `1423134370` or for line 7, fcv=voyapro and fcv=demelog and the relevant fmd's as well `fmd=1422183999,` and `fmd=1422206234;`

You do remember the first line `demelog voyapro naisjdf naismc decoide decoccm travide travccm equiccm mariccm` ?

My aim is to have the following format (I will use line 2 and line 7 as the example)

*line 2*

```
 fck=83;fcv=demelog;;;;;;;;;fck=83;fmd=1423134370;;;;;;;;;
```

*line 7*

```
 fck=83;;fcv=voyapro;;;;;;;;;fck=83;;fmd=1422270462;;;;;;;;;
```

As you can see, I have added extra columns both for fck=83 for the fcv and the fmd, related to this `demelog voyapro naisjdf naismc decoide decoccm travide travccm equiccm mariccm`

I thought doing it with awk or sed or python , even if I have not a clue on how to do it with python nor awk and sed.

Maybe I can add the `demelog voyapro naisjdf naismc decoide decoccm travide travccm equiccm mariccm` in a separate file and then do a search with an index . If the string is here , I'm doing nothing. If it is not here, I'm adding an extra column.

Any helps are welcomed as I'm confused on where I should go technically speaking and starting to pull my hair.

**update**

This my attempt below in python

```
import re
word_list=    ['fcv=demelog','fcv=voyapro','fcv=naisjdf','fcv=naismc','fcv=decoide','fcv=decoccm','fcv=travide','fcv=travccm','fcv=equiccm','fcv=mariccm']


regex_string = "(?<=\W)(%s)(?=\W)" % ";".join(word_list)

find=re.compile(regex_string)

with open ("idcacf_v5.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')


finder = re.compile(regex_string)
string_to_be_searched = data

results = finder.findall ("%s " % string_to_be_searched)
result_set = set(results)
for word in word_list:
    print ("%s in string" % word)
```

As you can see, I need 2 things, to be able to index. Second thing is I need to be able to replicate what I have done with the fcv in term of order and put the same order with  `fmd=timestamp` of that line.

Comment: This looks like a CSV file with `;` as the separator. You might find things easier if you used the `csv` module. Also, it looks like there's a stray `,` in the first and last lines of the example data.

Comment: Hi @muru , aha ! how to use the csv module?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) are reasonably good. You can update the question if you find it confusing.

Comment: Crosspost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455745/how-can-i-add-an-extra-character-after-a-word-search

Comment: Hi @jasonwryan, not anymore. :) In the same time, not sure but from one place to another , people seems to be less enclined to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something I cobbled up using the CSV module:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import csv, sys

word_list = ['fcv=demelog','fcv=voyapro','fcv=naisjdf','fcv=naismc','fcv=decoide','fcv=decoccm','fcv=travide','fcv=travccm','fcv=equiccm','fcv=mariccm']

csvin = csv.reader (sys.stdin, delimiter=';')
csvout = csv.writer (sys.stdout, delimiter=';')
for row in csvin:
    word_list_fck = [row[0]] + word_list
    fmd_start = row[1:].index(row[0]) + 1
    row_fcv = row[:fmd_start]  # split fcv from fmd
    row_fmd = row[fmd_start:]
    out_row = [entry if entry in row_fcv else ''  for entry in word_list_fck]
    out_row = out_row + [row_fmd.pop(0) if out_row[i] != '' else '' for i in range(len(word_list_fck))]
    csvout.writerow (out_row)
```

Example output:

```
$ python3 test.py < test.txt
fck=83;;;fcv=naisjdf;fcv=naismc;;;;;;;fck=83;;;fmd=1422811694,;fmd=1422811694;;;;;;
fck=83;fcv=demelog;;;;;;;;;;fck=83;fmd=1423134370;;;;;;;;;
fck=83;fcv=demelog;;;;;;;;;;fck=83;fmd=1422292546;;;;;;;;;
fck=83;fcv=demelog;;;;;;;;;;fck=83;fmd=1421774352;;;;;;;;;
fck=83;;;;;;fcv=decoccm;;;;;fck=83;;;;;;fmd=1422853444;;;;
fck=83;;fcv=voyapro;;;;;;;;;fck=83;;fmd=1422270462;;;;;;;;
fck=83;fcv=demelog;fcv=voyapro;;;;;;;;;fck=83;fmd=1422183999,;fmd=1422206234,;;;;;;;;
```

Notes:

- I rely on the first element in the row (`fck=83` in the example cases) to be the entry separating the `fcv`s from the `fmd`s. If not, this thing is going to be a whole lot more complicated.
- Given the repeated `if bar in foo` in the list comprehensions, this might be very slow depending on the length of each row.

Regarding `out_row = [entry if entry in row_fcv else ''  for entry in word_list_fck]`:

- Consider how the desired output looks like when parsed by `csv.reader` to a list (taking, for example, the second line): `["fck=83" ,"fcv=demelog", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "fck=83", "fmd=1423134370", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]` - all the empty entries become empty strings.
- The output is supposed to contain empty entries for each `fcv` which did not appear in the input.
- Therefore, when building such a list for writing out using `csv.writer`, I use empty strings for all the `fcv` entries which do not appear in `row_fcv` (`if entry in row_fcv else ''`).

Comment: Wow. very elegant. Let me have a test.

Comment: I made a change in the second `if` check.

Comment: Hi @muru, can you explain the code a bit more, please?

Comment: Sure, which parts?

Comment: That part @muru `out_row = [entry if entry in row_fcv else ''  for entry in word_list_fck]`

Comment: @AndyK see if the update helps.